# gdb detected a segmentation fault. How to pinpoint the exact source?

Tags: c++, gdb

```
(gdb) s
Things:action (this=0x7fffffffdce0, packet=0x62c980) at file:41
41              if( thing->work(data) ) {
(gdb) s
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004040e1 in Things:action (this=0x7fffffffdce0, packet=0x62c980) at file:41
41              if( thing->work(data) ) {
```

In a `backtrace`, call to work(data) is a last one; and the segmentation happened (as it seems) before the GDB-managed process entered `work(data)`. In a `list`, there is no declaration of work(data), so guessing that more code was executed, than is shown by backtrace and latest step.

1. Can that segfault come from the bad pointer being passed as a function argument in a bad manner (without "extern C", or some other preparations)? (assuming no function code was executed)
2. How to get a detailed trace to determine, was any `work()` code executed after entering the function, or the error happened right at the moment, when process tried to enter the function, thereby passing it's arguments to libc?

Comment: Is `this` valid ? `0x7fffffffdce0` seems quite high to me.

Comment: Yeah...really looks like `thing` might be an invalid pointer.

Comment: @icecrime: Yeah, `thing` has been clobbered.

Comment: you should try [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: @icecrime ok.. went to a Things source and set an assert, (thing != NULL). In the test case, assertion failed; in the default case it keeps working; seems that a problem is tracked and GDB really caught the problem at exact source line (requesting `thing->`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment : I believe that the execution never reached `work(data)` because the `this` pointer is invalid (`0x7fffffffdce0` looks like garbage). The SIGSEGV is on `this->`.

Has the object been destroyed / deleted at some point, and have you kept a reference or pointer to it ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `work()` can't have been started unless it's inline, or you it would have been on the top of the backtrace...

I would try disassembling to see what instruction triggered the SIGSEGV and go from there.